# How does a static site generator help vs. just a CDN?

Tags: gatsby, hugo, static-site

Noob question here.  I'm seeing buzz about static site generators like Hugo and Gatsby but I don't understand their benefits.

It is my understanding that they will dump out your site as a pile of static HTML pages that you can then host on any CDN for barebones webserver.

My question is how is this any different than the normal operation of a CDN, which would cache a static HTML version of your page after it has been accessed by a user.

What are the benefits of generating the whole site staticly vs. it getting cached piecemeal on a CDN as it is used?

Thanks all.